# Why removing entity by id method does not return entity?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following situation:

First of all about versions. I am using spring boot and spring-data-jpa:1.11.4.RELEASE.

I have the following repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ActivitiesRepository extends JpaRepository<Activity, Long> {
//...

Optional<Activity> removeActivityById(Long activityId);

//...
}
```

The app is up and running, but when i try to test this method i have received not an entity but:

```
result= {Optional@10183} "Optional[1]"
  value = {Integer@10186} "1"
```

Could some one explain why this happening? I want to receive an Entity as a result. How can I write this method without using

```
CrudRepository#delete(ID id)
```

and additional checks?
I have read [Appendix D: Repository query return types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types) about Optional, but cannot figure out what is going on and why the app was not failed at build time if something wrong with query methods.

Comment: So your true question is that you wonder why you get an Optional with an Integer 1 rather than an Optional with an Activity entity instance? It seems what you get is the number of affected records. Which would make sense in an update-type of query.

Comment: You are right! But here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#...... at Example 6 i see removeByLastname(String lastname) that returns an entity list. And i am confused and need to understand the difference.

Comment: Obviously it is the return type, which in the example is a List that can hold multiple results. That seems to be the contract; either the return type is a single value which will be the update count, or it is a List which will hold the affected entities. If you change your own code to be a List, you'll probably get what you want - a List holding one entity.

Comment: @Gimby, thank you, i will test it and post the response here. By the way, for me is still not quite understandable for what reason return list with one element if we try to delete by field that with pk constraint.

Comment: @Gimby, i have tested with `List<Activity> removeActivityById(Long activityId);` and in this case i can see an entity. Also continue to investigate why it behaves in such way...